# who worth you most / who worths you most

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, sentence-construction

"Do not overlook the worth of the person
who worth you most."

Or,

"Do not overlook the worth of the person
who worths you most."

I wanted to say, the person for whom you are worthy and important most.

I'm not sure of if the use of the word and sentence and grammatically is it ok? and says what I want to say?

Answer (score 11):

I think you mean:

*Don't overlook the worth of the person who values you the most.*

"Worth" isn't a verb.

Comment: I'd preserve the flow of the original sentence: *Don't overlook the value of the person who values you the most.*

Answer (score 3):

@Chenmunka's close, but actually, I think you mean:

> *Don't overlook the **esteem** of the person who **values** you the most.*

Both @Chenmunka's sentence (with "worth of the person") and @helix's correction ("the value of the person") refer to the esteem in which "you" hold *them*, not the esteem in which they hold you.

That is, if you mean "Consider the source.  If you think highly of someone, then don't discount it if they think highly of you." then, yes:

> *Don't overlook the **worth** of the person who values you the most*

is close to what you want (but "overlook" is problematic).

If, however, you mean, "Don't discount the good opinion of someone holds of you just because they hold such a high opinion of you", then

> *Don't overlook the **esteem** of the person who values you the most.*

is what you want.

Comment: Excellent point! I originally thought the same as Chenmuka, but it's entirely possible the OP could mean this. Thanks for mentioning it! +1

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, 'worth' is not a verb, and the verb you most likely want to use here is 'value'. But with that aside, it looks like you're asking specifically about the verb conjugation in this expression, rather than the choice of word.

In that respect, the correct expression would be:

> *Do not overlook the worth of the person who **values** you most.*

This is because in this sentence 'value' is being used as a third person verb. In English, [regular verbs](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/regularverbs.shtml) such as 'value' are typically conjugated with an 's' or 'es' at the end in the singular third person form (but not others).

Here is the [Conjugation of 'value'](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-value.html) and a useful website for checking other verbs' conjugations.

I hope that helps.