# How to It's the tie that's not worth you

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

I am having problems understanding the what the person means by 'It is the tie that's not worth you'. Does he mean that the other person with the tie, is not worthy of wearing the tie? Or the tie does not fit the person?

P.S. I tried consulting this:
[who worth you most / who worths you most](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22158/who-worth-you-most-who-worths-you-most)

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a good example of irony. It isn't even the sort of phrase that an English speaker would naturally say.

The meaning is that the tie does not have enough value to be worth wearing by the person. In other words, the person is worthy of a much better tie.

I think the irony is supposed to be that, instead of saying, "That's an ugly/cheap-looking tie", which would insult the other person's taste in clothing, they compliment the person by saying that the person is worthy of a better tie.

Comment: Yeah - it doesn't really work, does it? If the first guy had asked *Am I worthy of wearing this tie?* (admittedly, a bogglingly unlikely thing to say), the second guy might *feasibly* reply *The tie isn't worthy of **you**!* But really, it looks like a lame attempt by some non-native speaker to riff off the "In Soviet Russia" reversal meme (as in *In Soviet Russia, TV watches **you**!*).